# How to pass multiple value to google map V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

How to plot more number of markers in google map

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            // When map page opens get location and display map
            $('.page-map').live("pagecreate", function() {


            var latt=[13.0423734,12.918907];
            var lang=[80.2727993,80.145264];
            for(i=0; i<latt.length;i++)
            {
            initialize(latt[i],lang[i]);
            }
            });

            function initialize(lat,lng) 
            {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng, 
                  map: map, 
                  title:"Hello World!"
              });   
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: have you tried to simply construct another marker as you do with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays.

```
// When map page opens get location and display map
$('.page-map').live("pagecreate", function() {
    var latt=[13.0423734,12.918907];
    var lang=[80.2727993,80.145264];
    initialize(latt, lang);
});

function initialize(lat_arr,lng_arr)
{
    // Assuming first array element is where you want the map centered
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_arr[0],lng_arr[0]);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    var markers = [];
    // start i at 0 if you want a marker at the center as well
    for(var i = 1; i < lat_arr.length; i++) {
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_arr[i], lng_arr[i]);
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Hello World!"
        });
    }
}
```